# `vpnkit-bridge` and `com.docker.backend` are listening 49226

Tags: docker, macos

`vpnkit-bridge` and `com.docker.backend` are listening 49226

```bash
$ sudo lsof -PiTCP -sTCP:LISTEN
COMMAND   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
com.docke IPv4 0x64a5244679cda855      0t0  TCP *:49226 (LISTEN)
vpnkit-br IPv4 0x64a5244679cda855      0t0  TCP *:49226 (LISTEN)
$ vpnkit --version
5e1ae77c1845c16e4bc3cbf79e76b0d28beb1689
```

OS release: `macOS Monterey 12.1 Release`

I am wondering what `port 49226` is for and if there is any security concern.